# How to insert multiple passanger informations like name, age, gender and berth information from html form in database using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am making a booking system in which I made a form which will ask form the number of passengers and on taking input it will make fields for the passengers. Now I want to insert the data into the database I do not how to do this, please help.

```
def book(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    obj = request.POST.get('n_pass',False)
    for i in range(int(obj)):
        obje = Book(name = request.POST['name'+i],user_id = request.POST['user_id'],gender = request.POST['gender'+i],berth = request.POST['berth'+i],age = request.POST['age'+i],j_date = request.POST['j_date'],train_no = request.POST['train_no'])
        obje.save()
    return render(request,'book.html',{'msg':"Success"})                
return render(request,'book.html')
```

I tried to use loop to get it store but it is not storing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/).

I'd suggest you work through djangos excellent [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/).
That should get you started.

If you encounter more specific problems you could come back and ask a question about them.

Comment: Actually, I create a model but the problem is that I can insert only one row in a table at a time , I do not know how to insert multiple rows at a time in database

Comment: Maybe start by including your code into the question! I have no idea where you are stuck by looking into your question. How does the user enter its data? How does your views.py currently look?

Comment: please include your model and your template as well. i have no idea what n_pass is. How are the passengers passed along in the request?